# How to convert data type longtext with base64 to image from data base to gridview on specific column?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gridview, base64

i call a database to get data in column with data type `longtext` that contain string that i've encoded from image with **base64**

```
 string insertQuery = "SELECT product_id, picture FROM product WHERE aksi != 'Deleted' ";
 etc...
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dtblProduct;
```

the column with data type `longtext` is `picture`

i want to convert the `longtext`'s data in column picture with **base64** and display it on gridview along with `product id`

i've tried, but the error says *'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. '*

```
string showpic = dataGridView1.Columns[1].ToString();
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(showpic);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
Image myimage = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
imageColumn.Image = myimage;
```

Comment: Have you checked what `dataGridView1.Columns[1].ToString();` actually returns? Btw, you just need `var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(showpic)), true);` When `showpic` will contain the real data.

Comment: it returns the data on column `picture`. btw how to display the picture that you've converted along with other data on gridview?

Comment: You can add a Column to either the DataTable (and use a *special* constructor to assign its value from another Column), or add a `DataGridViewImageColumn` to the DataGridView (not a DataGrid or a GridView) and use one of the DGV events (CellFormatting, for example) to *format* the data (this can be *expensive* if not handled correctly). Fix the immediate problem, then, if you want, you can update your question and ask for this instead. The *string problem* is trivial, this other question is more interesting.

Comment: Btw2, it doesn't *return the data on column picture*, it returns something else. You haven't checked the content of `showpic` yet.

Comment: i'm totally confused. i've searched these issues, it does return the data on column picture but it goes error because of non-base64 characters. probably because space of paragraph, when i get the data by  `dataGridView1.Columns[1].ToString();` the String in visual studio can't accept the paragraph space so it turns to something else, then when i convert it by base64 it goes error. Any solution? @Jimi

Comment: This: `dataGridView1.Columns[1].ToString();` does not return the content of a Cell, it returns the basic `Columns[1]` definition: Column type, `Name` and `Index`. The content (Value) of, e.g., `Column1;Row0` is returned by `dataGridView1[1, 0].Value.ToString();`, as a string representation. Or `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to display a picture in a column of datagridview.

I suggest that when designing the form, add two columns in the datagridview, namely product_id, picture.

The data type of the picture column is DataGridViewImageColumn.

You can try the following code to solve this problem.

```
public void Table()
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("…");           
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select product_id,picture from product WHERE aksi != 'Deleted'", conn);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string id, base64;
                id = reader["product_id"].ToString();
                base64 = reader["picture"].ToString();
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Image img = (Image)binFormatter.Deserialize(memStream);                            
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { id,img});
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Table();
      }
```

Result:
[image]